# Android mobile push notification to end user without installing the App

Tags: android, mobile, geofencing

I am trying to build mobile marketing / campaign via Android smartphones and `geofencing`. Mobile Apps will be developed for certain customers.

Now i need to know if the end device has not installed our developed Mobile Apps still is it possible to send push notification or not at the end device.

Comment: no its not possible

Comment: No, it's not possible and never will because it will be spamming.

Answer (score 3):

Push notifications are app specific. If there is no app installed, then its notifications can not be shown too.

Comment: If the end device has other Apps which commonly installed by end users e.g Google Map or etc then is it possible to push notification through our developed Apps ?  Thanks in advance

Comment: You can send your own push notification only if your own application is installed on user's device